# Why this query still taking time to return 500K records having 14 columns

Tags: indexing, sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization, execution-time, sql-execution-plan

I am looking for some advise regarding improvement in query ( if any).

Please look at below Query Plan and notice that most of the tables are using Index Seek ( Non-clustered) and Nested Loops. Still this query is taking 00:01:17 time to extract 500K rows. Please suggest if anything wrong or needs improvement in it.

```html
StmtText
  |--Top(TOP EXPRESSION:((500000)))
   |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[CardMerchant].[CardID], [Expr1028]) OPTIMIZED WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH)
        |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[Merchant].[MerchantID], [Expr1027]) WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH)
        |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[MerchantGroup].[MerchantGroupID], [Expr1026]) WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH)
        |    |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[RegionalGroup].[ID]))
        |    |    |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[Company].[CompanyID]))
        |    |    |    |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[Company].[CompanyGroupID]))
        |    |    |    |    |    |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[Company].[IX_CompanyGroupID]))
        |    |    |    |    |    |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[CompanyGroup].[IX_Name]), SEEK:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[CompanyGroup].[CompanyGroupID]=[MyDatabase].[dbo].[Company].[CompanyGroupID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
        |    |    |    |    |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[RegionalGroup].[IX_CompanyID]), SEEK:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[RegionalGroup].[CompanyID]=[MyDatabase].[dbo].[Company].[CompanyID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
        |    |    |    |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[MerchantGroup].[IX_RegionalGroupId]), SEEK:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[MerchantGroup].[RegionalGroupID]=[MyDatabase].[dbo].[RegionalGroup].[ID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
        |    |    |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[Merchant].[IX_MerchantGroupID]), SEEK:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[Merchant].[MerchantGroupID]=[MyDatabase].[dbo].[MerchantGroup].[MerchantGroupID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
        |    |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[CardMerchant].[IX_CardMerchant_MerchantID]), SEEK:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[CardMerchant].[MerchantID]=[MyDatabase].[dbo].[Merchant].[MerchantID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
        |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[View_Transaction].[IX_MerchantCardID]), SEEK:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[View_Transaction].[MerchantCardID]=[MyDatabase].[dbo].[CardMerchant].[CardID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
```

Shall be very thankful to you.

Cheers,

Comment: "Query plan" is a good start, but you need to get a better idea of estimated (or actual) cost for your particular data set.  Look at these two links: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.11.sqlquery.aspx (SQL 2005, but still largely relevant) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983386/where-is-the-query-analyzer-in-sql-server-management-studio-2008-r2.

Comment: Hi User FoggyDay, Thank you for comment. FYI, its a estimated query plan.

Comment: Run the query and post the **actual** execution plan - is it roughly the same as the estimated one? If not: then you might have a problem with statistics being out of date ...

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for comment. Yes, it's exactly same as estimated. That's y I didn't mention earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The question might not be: *why does it take 1:17 to fetch the information*, but rather: *why does it take 1:17 to get the data in my client application*.

Where do you run this query? If it is in SSMS then most probably a lot of the time is 'lost' in loading those 500k records into the results-grid. If you want to 'measure' the query you could switch on the 'discard results after execution' option, or you could simply dump the result in a different table. Both still have some overhead on top of the actual query, but a lot less than building a large grid will have.

In SSMS

- open a new query
- in the menu *select Query / Query options*
- select the Results pane
- check the "discard result after execution"