# Getting Entity Framework to work with SQL Server geospatial indexes

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, geospatial

We've got a fairly simple table that we're trying to query with Entity Framework, that looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EFBlkFireRisks](
    [EFBlkFireRiskId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EFStateId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Lat] [decimal](18, 8) NOT NULL,
    [Lon] [decimal](18, 8) NOT NULL,
    [AdjustedPremiumMultiplier] [decimal](18, 4) NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [GeoLocation] [geography] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.EFBlkFireRisks] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EFBlkFireRiskId] ASC
)
```

It has a geospatial index on the GeoLocation column, like so:

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [IX_EFBlkFireRisks_Spatial] ON [dbo].[EFBlkFireRisks]
(
    [GeoLocation]
)USING  GEOGRAPHY_AUTO_GRID
```

We're trying to find the entry in that table that's the closest to a given lat/lon point.

The C# query looks like this:

```
var geoPoint = SqlSchemaFunctions.GetDbGeography(lat, lon);
var query = ctx.BulkFireRisks
    .Where(x => x.EFStateId == stateId && x.GeoLocation.Distance(geoPoint) != null)
    .OrderBy(x => x.GeoLocation.Distance(geoPoint));
var bfr = query.First();
```

The SQL that query generates looks basically like this:

```
declare @p3 sys.geography set @p3=convert(sys.geography,0xE6100000010C8FC2F5285CFF434052B81E85EB515AC0)
declare @p4 sys.geography set @p4=convert(sys.geography,0xE6100000010C8FC2F5285CFF434052B81E85EB515AC0)
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Project1].[EFBlkFireRiskId] AS [EFBlkFireRiskId], 
    [Project1].[EFStateId] AS [EFStateId], 
    [Project1].[GeoId] AS [GeoId], 
    [Project1].[Lat] AS [Lat], 
    [Project1].[Lon] AS [Lon], 
    [Project1].[GeoLocation] AS [GeoLocation], 
    [Project1].[AdjustedPremiumMultiplier] AS [AdjustedPremiumMultiplier],
    [Project1].C1 as Distance
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[GeoLocation].STDistance(@p__linq__1) AS [C1], 
        [Extent1].[EFBlkFireRiskId] AS [EFBlkFireRiskId], 
        [Extent1].[EFStateId] AS [EFStateId], 
        [Extent1].[GeoId] AS [GeoId], 
        [Extent1].[Lat] AS [Lat], 
        [Extent1].[Lon] AS [Lon], 
        [Extent1].[GeoLocation] AS [GeoLocation], 
        [Extent1].[AdjustedPremiumMultiplier] AS [AdjustedPremiumMultiplier]
        FROM [dbo].[EFBlkFireRisks] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE (11 = [Extent1].[EFStateId]) AND ([Extent1].[GeoLocation].STDistance(@p__linq__0) IS NOT NULL)
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 [geography],@p__linq__1 [geography]',@p__linq__0=@p3,@p__linq__1=@p4
```

And that query does *not* use the index - placing it in a loop and running it 10 times takes roughly 30 seconds (whether I execute it manually via SQL, or run it via EF from C#).

However, it's possible to remove the `sp_executesql` bit, and run the query directly, like so:

```
declare @p3 sys.geography set @p3=convert(sys.geography,0xE6100000010C8FC2F5285CFF434052B81E85EB515AC0)
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Project1].[EFBlkFireRiskId] AS [EFBlkFireRiskId], 
    [Project1].[EFStateId] AS [EFStateId], 
    [Project1].[GeoId] AS [GeoId], 
    [Project1].[Lat] AS [Lat], 
    [Project1].[Lon] AS [Lon], 
    [Project1].[GeoLocation] AS [GeoLocation], 
    [Project1].[AdjustedPremiumMultiplier] AS [AdjustedPremiumMultiplier],
    [Project1].C1 as Distance
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[GeoLocation].STDistance(@p3) AS [C1], 
        [Extent1].[EFBlkFireRiskId] AS [EFBlkFireRiskId], 
        [Extent1].[EFStateId] AS [EFStateId], 
        [Extent1].[GeoId] AS [GeoId], 
        [Extent1].[Lat] AS [Lat], 
        [Extent1].[Lon] AS [Lon], 
        [Extent1].[GeoLocation] AS [GeoLocation], 
        [Extent1].[AdjustedPremiumMultiplier] AS [AdjustedPremiumMultiplier]
        FROM [dbo].[EFBlkFireRisks] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE (11 = [Extent1].[EFStateId]) AND ([Extent1].[GeoLocation].STDistance(@p3) IS NOT NULL)
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] asc
```

And *that* query takes not 30 *seconds* to run, but 30 *milliseconds*.

I'm scratching my head. Any idea why the two queries have such radically different execution patterns? Any idea how to get EF to work with this particular geospatial index? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT 6/18 -
If I try to add an index hint to the slower `sp_executesql` query, I get this error message:

> The query processor could not produce a query plan for a query with a spatial index hint.  Reason: Spatial indexes do not support the comparator supplied in the predicate.

The same hint works - or at least, doesn't error out - on the other query.

The query plan for the slow query looks like this:

[image: Geospatial Query Plan]

In other words, it's not picking up the geospatial index. The query plan for the fast version *is* picking up the index, and looks like you'd expect:

[image]

This is running on SQL Server 2014:

> (Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) 
>       Feb 20 2014 20:04:26 
>       Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>       Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: )

Comment: Hms, seems to be an issue with MS SQL server then. Have you tried using the query analyzer tools provided? (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983386/where-is-the-query-analyzer-in-sql-server-management-studio-2008-r2)

Comment: Also, in your query, what happens if you force an index by using the `with` keyword?

Comment: @flindeberg - The query plan for the fast query looks like you'd expect. The query plan for the slow query only shows up as `Execute Proc: Cost 0.0%`. I've edited the answer above to show what happens when I try to use the `WITH (INDEX (IX_EFBlkFireRisks_Spatial))` hint.

Comment: @flindeberg - See my edits above. The `with` hint errors out, and the query plan for the slow query is trying to go off of the main clustered index - it's not using (and apparently not able to use) the geospatial index.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I figured it out.

Turns out that the two queries weren't precisely identical: the `sp_executesql` version had *two* parameters, while the fast one only had one: and that was the key. This query (with just one parameter) executes like you'd expect:

```
declare @p3 sys.geography
set @p3=convert(sys.geography,0xE6100000010C8FC2F5285CFF434052B81E85EB515AC0)
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Project1].[EFBlkFireRiskId] AS [EFBlkFireRiskId], 
    [Project1].[EFStateId] AS [EFStateId], 
    [Project1].[GeoId] AS [GeoId], 
    [Project1].[Lat] AS [Lat], 
    [Project1].[Lon] AS [Lon], 
    [Project1].[GeoLocation] AS [GeoLocation], 
    [Project1].[AdjustedPremiumMultiplier] AS [AdjustedPremiumMultiplier]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[EFBlkFireRiskId] AS [EFBlkFireRiskId], 
        [Extent1].[EFStateId] AS [EFStateId], 
        [Extent1].[GeoId] AS [GeoId], 
        [Extent1].[Lat] AS [Lat], 
        [Extent1].[Lon] AS [Lon], 
        [Extent1].[GeoLocation] AS [GeoLocation], 
        [Extent1].[AdjustedPremiumMultiplier] AS [AdjustedPremiumMultiplier], 
        [Extent1].[GeoLocation].STDistance(@p__linq__0) AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[EFBlkFireRisks] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE (11 = [Extent1].[EFStateId]) AND ([Extent1].[GeoLocation].STDistance(@p__linq__0) IS NOT NULL)
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 [geography]',@p__linq__0=@p3
```

And the way to get that query in LINQ is like this:

```
var geoPoint = DbGeography.PointFromText(string.Format("POINT({0} {1})", lon, lat), 4326);
var q2 = (from b in ctx.BulkFireRisks
          let distance = b.GeoLocation.Distance(geoPoint)
          where b.EFStateId == stateId && distance != null
          orderby distance
          select b);
var bfr = q2.First();
```

The key is to define any `sys.geography` variable just once.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, that will surely help more :)